# Error with Amazon Fire Tablet 10 factory reset

Tags: factory-reset

So I've got an amazon fire tablet 10 and my younger brother was messing around with the settings and set the screen width to 100dpi as a prank and the phone's screen ended up turning black and he couldn't reverse it. I tried my luck with it but failed terribly while trying, I tried to use the fire toolbox to try factory reset it but that didn't seem to work well.

I then tried using the fire toolbox to try load the bootloader (even though I have little knowledge about it) and that option fell flat as well.

I usually use this tablet to test run projects that I found fascinating online but I can't do that anymore with this new-founded dilemma.

If anyone has experience resetting androids of any sort or more specifically amazon fire tablets, your inputs will be very much appreciated.

Comment: https://www.hardreset.info/devices/amazon/amazon-fire-hd-10-2017/recovery-mode

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Redmi note 8 is on recovery mode. Booting constantly but not booting to system](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/241727/redmi-note-8-is-on-recovery-mode-booting-constantly-but-not-booting-to-system)

Answer (score 0):

Screen resolution is stored in userdata, factory reset will fix it. changed settings does not apply to recovery mode, you can enter by pressing Volume Up + Power buttons.

Note: factory reset from recovery will activate (FRP) factory reset protection. google play account is still required to unlock FRP afterwards