# Redmi note 8 is on recovery mode. Booting constantly but not booting to system

Tags: redmi

I changed the dpi from 392 to 1000 in my Rei note 8 in developer option. After that it constantly is on booting Loop to recovery mode. And I can not wipe my data cause it is only there . (Local drive). So I can't afford to loose data because some of my important information and sodt copies of certificates and other identification proof are there.  How can I get them back cause only option there is to wipe data because mi assistant is useless here.(no function).
So please kindly do take some time to help me if you can. I am eagerly waiting for the solution.  Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad screen resolution permanently crashes Poco F1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234549/bad-screen-resolution-permanently-crashes-poco-f1)